# How to implement multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing in Python to sort independent lists.
For example, I have a dictionary of an int as a key and a list as a value.

I tried to implement a simple program, but I have a difficulty to store the sorted list in a defaultdict again and return it to the main module.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def fun(id, user_data):
    user_data.sort()
    return user_data

# users_data is a defaultdict of id as key and a list as a value
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for id,user_data in users_data.items():
        P= Process(target=fun,args=(id,user_data))
        P.start()
        P.join()
```

Comment: I seem it may be because of the typo in your fun function. It should be return instead of retrun.

Comment: What's the point of using Processes if you're waiting for each one right after you start it? A more idiomatic way of doing that is adding the Process objects to a list and then `join`ing them, or more simply - using a [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo. Yes, join should be separated from start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use Manager to share data between processes.
Also, as @Tomerikoo mentioned in the comments, the way you are doing it right now will not actually result in multiprocessing as `P.join()` just after `P.start()` will the script pause to let that process finish, thus resulting in a serial execution flow rather than parallel.

You can do something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def sort_list(user_id, user_data, interprocess_dict):
    user_data.sort()
    interprocess_dict[user_id] = user_data


users_data = {}
users_data[1] = [5, 2, 1]
users_data[3] = [10, 12, 1]


def main():
    interprocess_dict = Manager().dict()
    processes = []
    for user_id, user_data in users_data.items():
        proc = Process(target=sort_list, args=(user_id, user_data, interprocess_dict,))
        processes.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
    
    for user_id, user_data in interprocess_dict.items():
        print('{}: {}'.format(user_id, user_data))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT:**

Its better to limit the number of processes to the number of hardware CPU units available as sorting a list is 100% CPU bound operation.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp


def sort_list(user_id, user_data, interprocess_dict):
    user_data.sort()
    interprocess_dict[user_id] = user_data


def prepare_data():
    users_data = {}
    for i in range(1000):
        users_data[i] = list(range(10000, 0, -1))
    return users_data


def main():
    # mp.set_start_method('spawn') # Only valid on OSX
    interprocess_dict = mp.Manager().dict()
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    users_data = prepare_data()
    for user_id, user_data in users_data.items():
        pool.apply_async(sort_list, args = (user_id, user_data, interprocess_dict,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    for user_id, user_data in interprocess_dict.items():
        print('{}: {}'.format(user_id, user_data))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @anmol, I tried this solution, but it is still taking a long time!

Comment: I have 600 ids, each with a list of 9000 item, I couldn't see any increase in time after implementing the multiprocessing!

Comment: @ghana I realized that we should probably use `Pool` for this as creating more processes than the number of hardware CPU units will make it slower.

Comment: BTW, `cpu_count` is the default for the `Pool` constructor so it is redundant

Comment: I tried to print the whole interprocess_dict without the loop, but it prints an empty dict!, why?, is it because of the async?

Comment: No it should still print. I hope you are printing it after the `pool.join()` line.